# c program to copy the data between two specific words from one file to another

Tags: c

```
with header;
with linker;
package body(* some text )
vin float32=2.0;
mis float32=3.0;
raj pointtodatatype.array(.234,-.2344323343,.234555656,.2334445344)
rex float32=3*3.142345634;
procedure
```

I want to read this data from the text file and copy the data between the lines starting `package` up to the line starting `procedure`.

So the output would be the another text file containing the following:

```
vin float32=2.0;
mis float32=3.0;
raj pointtodatatype.array(.234,-.2344323343,.234555656,.2334445344)
rex float32=3*3.142345634;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ].  Also notice that asking the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684511/c-program-to-read-the-content-from-a-text-file-between-two-lines-and-copy-it-to) several times is not popular, and you don't seem to have learned much from yesterday's episode (though this is expressed a bit better than yesterday's question). Does `sed` count as a C program to do the job?  Which language are you interested in?  The C solution won't be a good C++ solution, and the C++ solution won't be a C solution.  Choose one — not both.

Comment: i m more comfortable with c

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: Hi Jonathan, I am looking for similar solution but in bash(sed/grep). Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[4096];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        if (strncmp(line, "package ", sizeof("package ")-1) == 0)
        {
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
            {
                if (strncmp(line, "procedure\n", sizeof("procedure\n")-1) == 0)
                    break;
                fputs(line, stdout);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code reads from standard input and writes to standard output.  If you have data in `file1` and want the results in `file2`, use:

```
./program <file1 >file2
```

This is one of the beauties of standard input/standard output filters and shell I/O redirection.

*Tested.*  Assuming no trailing blanks after the `procedure`, the code now looks for `"procedure\n"`. If you have to allow for possible trailing blanks or no trailing blanks, the comparison for `procedure` is fiddlier.